# Problem in Converting VARCHAR to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am having a problem in changing the datatype from VARCHAR(50) TO INT for a column. I tried a lot but still not getting it and that to be without using variables and also after need to add identity to that column after conversion from varchar to int.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: ...also some sample values for the catcher column would be good.

Comment: I have a column called STEM_ID varchar(50). I would like to change it as STEM_ID int and also need to assign Identity to this column.

Comment: @Shahsra - again, please post what you have **tried**, some **values from the column**, and the **error message** that you got when it didn't work

Comment: select convert(int,[_STEM_ID]) from [MS].[dbo].[SD]

Comment: ERROR:    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name '_REC_ID'.

Comment: I don't know why its showing like that... I checked the column but it showing the same column name....

Comment: and the values are 1 2 3 4 5  6  7 8

Comment: and i dont want that column with that values thats why i want to add identity to that column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN`is not supported (as in your case), changing a column type is best done in four steps:

- add a new column with the proper type
- update the database to match the values in old and new column
- using [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx), swap the name of the new column with the old column
- drop the old column

An alternative is to:

- create a new table with the desired columns
- copy the data into the new table
- use sp_rename to swap the names between the old and new table
- drop the old table

The best path depends on many factors, like size of data, existing constraints, foreign keys referencing the table, non-clustered indexes, views and user functions referencing the table, replication, existing triggers and procedures and so on and so forth. It is not possible to give a simple answer because the problem itself is complicated when one considers *all* the implications.

Comment: Hi,  I am trying to add a new column as you said. But its showing me an error saying: Msg 2744, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Multiple identity columns specified for table 'SD_Channel_Mapped'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.

Comment: So what i undestood is I cannot create two identical columns in a single table. But 2 days back I have created two identical columns at a time and it workeed. So I am thing what should be the reason.

Comment: You cannot create two `IDENTITY` columns, not two identical columns. Its extremely unlikely you need two `IDENTITY` columns,  and your original post definitely does not call for that. You must be doing something more than what you described in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a multistep process such as:

```
/** Add new column with identity **/
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD NewColumnTempName INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1) DEFAULT (0)
GO

/** Allow us to enter values into the entity field **/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON;
GO

/** Push the data from the varchar column into the new column **/
UPDATE MyTable
SET NewColumnTempName = CAST(OldColumnName AS INT);
GO

/** Get rid of the old column **/
ALTER TABLE MyTable
DROP OldColumnName;
GO

/** Rename the newcolumn tot he old name **/
EXEC sp_rename 'MyTable.NewColumnTempName', 'OldColumnName', 'COLUMN';

/** Switch back on the identity column **/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF
GO
```

Comment: Good thinking, except that `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME COLUMN` is a pipe dream, not actual T-SQL syntax. Use `sp_rename` instead.

Comment: D'oh! Well spotted - amended accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious guess is that there is data in your column that cannot be converted to an INT. Does this return any results?

```
select ColumnYouWantToConvert
    from YourTable
    where isnumeric(ColumnYouWantToConvert) = 0
```

Comment: Don't forget `ISNUMERIC` is a buggy function...123E22 will return `1`

Comment: @JNK: Understood but, in this particular case, I think this may be "close enough for government work" to help identify the issue.

Comment: Thanks but still its showing me that the column name is incorrect.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name '_REC_ID'.

Answer (score 0):

You need drop DEFAULTS, CHECKS etc , ALTER colum  and recreate DEFAULTS, CHECKS and keys

```
ALTER TABLE T DROP CONSTRAINT C1
ALTER TABLE T DROP CONSTRAINT C2
ALTER TABLE T DROP CONSTRAINT C3
...
ALTER TABLE T ALTER COLUMN Cl int [null|notnull]
ALTER TABLE T ADD 
CONSTRAINT C1 ... ,
CONSTRAINT C2...,
CONSTRAINT C3...,
```